# HTML controls come automatically when fullscreen

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have got a video in my html code

```
    <video width="100%" class="posted_vid">
            <source src="uploaded_videos/<?php echo $Video; ?>">
    </video>                                

        <div class="video_controls">                        
                    <input type="range" id="font-1-size" value="0" class="video_range"  min="0"><br>
                    <img src="img/playicon.png" class="play_button">
                    <img src="img/pauseicon.png" class="pause_button">
                    <img src="img/volumeicon.png" class="volume_button">
                    <input type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" class="volume">
                    <span class="cur_time current_min">0:</span><span class="cur_time current_seconds">00</span>
                    <span class="duration">0:00</span>  
                   <img title="Fullscreen" src="img/fullscreen.png" class="fullscreen_vid">
       </div>

$("body").on('click', '.fullscreen_vid', function(event) {
    var vid = $(this).parent().siblings('.posted_vid')[0];
    if (vid.requestFullscreen) {
      vid.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (vid.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      vid.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (vid.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      vid.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    }   
});
```

Now when video is not fullscreen it has controllers built by me,but when it goes fullscreen my controller get hidden and default html controllers come instead.How should i disable that?

Comment: And where in the DOM are those controllers you created located? Presumably _not_ inside the element which you switch into fullscreen mode ...?

Comment: @CBroe i added the controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set the video fullscreen.  Set a DOM node containing both the video and your custom controls fullscreen.

```
<div id="container">
  <video width="100%" class="posted_vid">
    <source src="uploaded_videos/<?php echo $Video; ?>">
  </video>
  <div class="video_controls">
    <input type="range" id="font-1-size" value="0" class="video_range" min="0"><br>
    <img src="img/playicon.png" class="play_button">
    <img src="img/pauseicon.png" class="pause_button">
    <img src="img/volumeicon.png" class="volume_button">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" class="volume">
    <span class="cur_time current_min">0:</span><span class="cur_time current_seconds">00</span>
    <span class="duration">0:00</span>
    <img title="Fullscreen" src="img/fullscreen.png" class="fullscreen_vid">
  </div>
</div>
```

```
$("body").on('click', '.fullscreen_vid', function(event) {
  var vid = $('#container');  // <------ this 
  if (vid.requestFullscreen) {
    vid.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (vid.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    vid.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (vid.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    vid.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for helping me and at the same time enriching my infinitesimal brain with this useful information.